# How should we add an instantiation to an existing variable?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have written an Analyzer that correctly detects uninstantiated collections. Now I'm writing the appropriate CodeFixProvider that will give the option to instantiate it.

When I execute my code and look at the provided fix, it would simply remove the identifier and only keep the type. Where did I go wrong in my approach?

[image]

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CodeAction>> GetFixesAsync(Document document, TextSpan span, IEnumerable<Diagnostic> diagnostics, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
    var token = root.FindToken(span.Start);
    document.TryGetSemanticModel(out var semanticModel);
    var statement = token.Parent.Parent as VariableDeclarationSyntax;

    // Construct variable declaration
    var declarator = new SeparatedSyntaxList<VariableDeclaratorSyntax>();
    var identifier = statement.Variables[0].Identifier;
    var newType = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(statement.Type).Type;
    var newObject = SyntaxFactory.ObjectCreationExpression(type: SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(newType.Name));
    var equalsClause = SyntaxFactory.EqualsValueClause(newObject);
    declarator.Add(SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclarator(identifier, null, equalsClause));

    var newStatement = SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclaration(statement.Type, declarator);
    var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(statement, newStatement);

    return new[]
    {
        CodeAction.Create("Instantiate collection variable", document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot))
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that all types in Roslyn are immutable. That means that even operations like `Add()` don't actually modify the object they're called on, they return the modified object.

This means that after `Add()`, you have to work with the returned value, not the original object.

If you modify your code to the following, it will work:

```
declarator = declarator.Add(SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclarator(identifier, null, equalsClause));
```

Comment: That does seem to work, cheers. I'm not seeing the changes popup in the preview window but that might be because the added code is invalid: right now it gets added as `List<int> ident = newList;`. Is there any way to easily get the default constructor including generic type, or do I explicitly have to construct `[space]List<int>()`?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel AFAIK, when you want to generate some code with Roslyn, there is never an easy way, you always have to create the whole syntax node piece by piece.

Comment: You can always use SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression("new List<int>()") to have the parser build the syntax nodes for you.

Comment: @MattWarren: [I ended up doing that](https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/blob/master/Source/FormattingFixes/Utilities/RoslynUtils.cs), appreciate the suggestion. It would've been a lot more messier if I had to try to puzzle it all together with syntaxnodes.